# bash: how to check if a string starts with '#'?

Tags: regex, bash

In bash I need to check if a string starts with '#' sign. How do I do that?

This is my take --

```
if [[ $line =~ '#*' ]]; then
    echo "$line starts with #" ;
fi
```

I want to run this script over a file, the file looks like this --

```
03930
#90329
43929
#39839
```

and this is my script --

```
while read line ; do
    if [[ $line =~ '#*' ]]; then
        echo "$line starts with #" ;
    fi
done < data.in
```

and this is my expected output --

```
#90329 starts with #
#39839 starts with #
```

But I could not make it work, any idea?

Comment: With bash regular expressions, any quoted portions are treated as plain text.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No regular expression needed, a pattern is enough

```
if [[ $line = \#* ]] ; then
    echo "$line starts with #"
fi
```

Or, you can use parameter expansion:

```
if [[ ${line:0:1} = \# ]] ; then
    echo "$line starts with #"
fi
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the `[[` rules any more, but shouldn't `$line` be double-quote-protected, i.e. `[[ "$line" = \#* ]]`?

Comment: @bitmask Bash should quote automatically when `[[` is used.

Answer (score 6):

Just use shell glob using `==`:

```
line='#foo'
[[ "$line" == "#"* ]] && echo "$line starts with #"
#foo starts with #
```

It is important to keep `#` quoted to stop shell trying to interpret as comment.

Comment: Since you are using `[[` only one equals sign `=` is needed in the comparison.

Comment: `=` and `==` behave same way in this case.

Comment: Yes `=` also works but I think bash developers supported `==` to be compatible with other popular programming languages.

Answer (score 5):

If you additionally to the accepted answer want to allow **whitespaces** in front of the '#' you can use

```
if [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*#.* ]]; then
    echo "$line starts with #"
fi
```

With this

```
#Both lines
    #are comments
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read line ; 
do
    if [[ $line =~ ^#+ ]]; then
        echo "$line starts with #" ;
    fi
done < data.in
```

This will do the trick remove * with + 
+ matches 1 or more
while * matches 0 or more so in your code it will show number even if it does not start with '#'

Comment: It's enough to do: `[[ $line =~ ^# ]]`.